# Terraform execution order with locals block

Tags: terraform

We have a requirement with one of the terraform scripts to execute a python script, generate the output, and read the output file. We are trying to achieve this through the below method,

```
resource "null_resource" "get_data_plane_ip" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python myscript.py > output.json"
  }
   triggers = {
        always_run = "${timestamp()}"
   }
}

locals {
  var1 = jsondecode(file("output.json"))
}
```

The problem with the above method is, we have seen `locals` block gets executed before the python script gets executed through `local-exec` resource. So the terraform apply fails. we can't use `depends_on` in `locals` block to specify the order as well.
Any suggestion on how can we make sure `locals` gets executed only after `local-exec`  resource?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is external data: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source

Comment: We had tried external data as well but the problem with the external data we observed is, during terraform plan stage itself python script gets executed.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: The script I am executing makes a call to an endpoint, which creates an entry in the system and returns the value.  So the plan would make a call and return set of values, apply makes another call and returns another set of values

Comment: Ok then you would want to split the functionality for READ into the external data, and CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE into the null resource. Assuming you already may have done that (or will do that), then you may be able to exploit the `null_resource.get_data_plane_ip.id` in the schema to construct a dependency from the local onto the resource.

Comment: Actually, there is no READ operation at all. It's a single POST call that creates an entry and returns the values so they can't be separated.  That is the challenge here. Also with null resource the problem is, terraform plan fails since some of the values we are reading only exists during the apply phase.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use another `null_resource` resource in this situation.

For example, take the following configuration:

```
resource "null_resource" "get_data_plane_ip" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python myscript.py > output.json"
  }

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "dependent" {
  triggers = {
    contents = file("output.json")
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.get_data_plane_ip]
}

locals {
  var1 = jsondecode(null_resource.b.triggers.contents)
}

output "var1" {
  value = local.var1
}
```

The `null_resource.dependent` resource has an explicit dependency on the `null_resource.get_data_plane_ip` resource. Therefore, it will wait for the `null_resource.get_data_plane_ip` resource to be "created".

Since the `triggers` argument is of type `map(string)`, you can use the `file` function to read the contents of the `output.json` file, which returns a string.

You can then create a local variable to invoke `jsondecode` on the `triggers` attribute of the `null_resource.dependent` resource.

Comment: I like this approach. But I am still facing an issue, lets say if I am referencing ```var1.name``` in another resource, my terraform plan fails since ```name``` does not exist during the terraform plan phase.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html) says the following:

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation. We do not recommend using dynamic local files in Terraform configurations, but in rare situations where this is necessary you can use [the local_file data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) to read files while respecting resource dependencies.

There a few different things to note in this paragraph. The first is that the documentation recommends against doing what you are doing except as a last resort; I don't know if there's another way to get the result you were hoping for, so I'll leave you to think about that part, and focus on the other part...

[The `local_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) is a data resource type that just reads a file from local disk. Because it appears as a resource rather than as a language operator/function, it'll be a node in Terraform's dependency graph just like your `null_resource.get_data_plane_ip`, and so it can depend on that resource.

The following shows one way to write that:

```
resource "null_resource" "get_data_plane_ip" {
  triggers = {
    temp_filename = "${path.module}/output.json"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python myscript.py >'${self.triggers.temp_filename}'"
  }

}

data "local_file" "example" {
  filename = null_resource.get_data_plane_ip.triggers.temp_filename
}

locals {
  var1 = jsondecode(data.local_file.example.content)
}
```

---

Note that this sort of design will make your Terraform configuration *non-converging*, which is to say that you can never reach a point where `terraform apply` will report that there are no changes to apply. That's often undesirable, because a key advantage of the declarative approach is that you can know you've reached a desired state and thus your remote system matches your configuration. If possible, I'd suggest to try to find an alternative design that *can* converge after selecting a particular IP address, though that'd typically mean representing that "data plane IP" as a resource itself, which may require writing a custom provider if you're interacting with a bespoke system.

I've not used it myself so I can't *recommend* it, but I notice that there's a community provider in the registry which offers [a `shell_script_resource` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/scottwinkler/shell/latest/docs/resources/shell_script_resource), which might be useful as a compromise between running commands in provisioners and writing a whole new provider. It seems like it allows you to write a script for `create` where the result would be retained as part of the resource state, and thus you could refer to it from other resources.